# Comparing slopes of two linear lines

Tags: math, geometry

Let say we have linear exp **y=ax+b**. Supposed we have: y1=0.5 x and y2=1.5 x. I can conclude easily that y2 has higher slope than y1 since a2=1.5 >a1=0.5.

Now let consider the case of negative slope. If i have **y3=-2x** and **y4=-0.5x**. ***Is it correct if I say y4 has higher slope than y3 because a4=-0.5>a3=-2?*** I am confused about this case when i draw y3, y4. If there is same \Delta(x) when x moves from the left to right, I can see the y3 falls/decreases faster than y4. In this sense, it might be said **"y3 has higher slope than y4".** Please anyone help to clarify this problem for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a purely mathematical question.

Comment: Thuy, is this related to any programming?

Comment: @Tarik: it is just mathematical question. I can use R to calculate the slope by using lm(y~x). Once I get the slope y3, y4  I am not sure how i can compare them "mathematically". That's why i post this question here.

Comment: It would be interesting to consider the case of "nonlinear lines"

Comment: @claudv: Perhaps we can consider `f(x) = undefined, ∀ x ∈ R`. It is a "constant" function, so it is a "linear" function, but it is also not a line. :P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compare the absolute values of the slopes.
Compare |slope1| with  |slope2|

Programmatically, use the abs function. For a more precise answer, provide the programming language you are using.

Comment: So, your answer means y3 has higher slope that y4 since we compare their absolute slope values. Is it right?

Comment: Thanks @Tarik for your patience and kind support, I got your point.

Comment: Vertical lines will be a challenge.....

Comment: @duffymo Nice to point out. The equation is not anymore y=ax+b though. It's x=a. I am not sure she has to handle that case. Anyway, the slope is undefined and accordingly, a program would just print out the fact that the first, second or both lines are vertical. An undefined value can be represented by a NULL. Comparing a NULL with any value is NULL. After that, it's just a matter of printing out the fact that the slopes cannot be compared.